# Boolean AND and OR selected rows/columns in R, without creation of a temporary copy?

Tags: r, vectorization, large-data, boolean-logic

I have an extremely large matrix full of boolean TRUEs and FALSEs. I need to check certain column combinations to find rows where either all of the specified columns are true, or (in some cases) any of the specified columns are true.

I can do it using apply() and all():

```
> toymat <- matrix(sample(c(F,T),50,rep=T),5,10)
> toymat[,c(1,5,6)]
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

> apply(toymat[, c(1,5,6)],1,all)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

But if I invoke apply with a function that would change a value, it seems to be passing by value, not passing by reference. In other words it's creating a temporary copy of "toymat[, c(1,5,6)]" to run apply on (which would not be desirable, because the actual matrix is huge and the code will be doing this many times).

Is there a way I can AND or OR together an arbitrary number of selected columns or selected rows without a temporary copy being created?

Comment: if you stored it as a data.table you could do `dt[, purrr::pmap(.(V1, V5, V6), all)]`

Comment: Maybe `apply(toymat, 1, function(x) all(x[c(1, 5, 6)]))` would work for you?

Comment: If your problem is copies being made, check out package `data.table`. But it doesn't work on matrices, you need to coerce to class `data.table` first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for Rcpp. Just use:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector rowsums_bool(const LogicalMatrix& x,
                           const IntegerVector& ind_col) {

  int i, j, j2, n = x.nrow(), m = ind_col.size();
  IntegerVector res(n);      

  for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    j2 = ind_col[j] - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (x(i, j2)) res[i]++;
    } 
  }

  return res;
}

/*** R
toymat <- matrix(sample(c(F,T),50,rep=T),5,10)
toymat[,c(1,5,6)]
(tmp <- rowsums_bool(toymat, c(1,5,6)))
tmp == 3  ## ALL
tmp != 0  ## ANY
*/
```